# What's the difference and use of categories and inheritance?

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, objective-c-category

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between inheritance and Categories in Objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522341/difference-between-inheritance-and-categories-in-objective-c)

When should I use subclassing and when should I use categories?

Answer (score 0):

Subclass when you want to extend the functionality utilized by the base.

```
@interface MyObject: NSObject<SomeProtocol>
```

Add a category when you want to add a convenience method to code you may not control.

```
@interface UIView (MyViewAdditions)

- (void)recursiveEnumerateSubviewsUsingBlock:(void (^)(UIView *view, BOOL *stop))block;
```