# Dismiss Keyboard when touch began on UITableView and GoogleMap's View

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, keyboard

My project design:

`UINavigationController ---> UITableViewController ---> UIViewController`

I've a `UISeachBar` on `navigationItem.titleView`

I tried to use `UITapGestureRecognizer`, it works but not as expected. Keyboard only dismisses when I touch on an `UITableViewCell`.

I want `UITableView` responds to `touchesBegan` so that I could make the keyboard disappears whenever I touch on an `UITableViewCell` or just scroll on the table.

Besides that, my `UIViewController` contains a googlemap's View, it does respond to `touchesBegan` but only one first touch, after that, every other touches would be ignored.

Can anyone help, pls ?

**too long, didn't read:** i want to dismiss the virtual keyboard on `UITableView` likes safari or chrome: when the touch began, not when it ended

Comment: Have you tried subclassing UITableView and overriding the touch events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a subclass of UITableView like so:

```
subclassTB.h

 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface subClassTB : UITableView

@end


subclassTB.m
#import "subclassTB.h"


 @implementation subClassTB

 - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
}
*/
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    // do your stuff here 
    //NSLog(@"tap registered");
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
@end
```

and in your current controller initialize the table by using

`subclassTB *yourtable = [[subclassTB alloc]initWithFrame:youFrame style:yourStyle];`

Comment: I've tried as you said. It did dismiss the keyboard when I touched outside the keyboard. However, the touch event on `UITableViewCell`s got cancelled, even with `[super touchesBegan:withEvent:]`. Can you give me some further help ? thank you.

Comment: What events were you doing in UITableViewCell? and can you provide some codes. I already tested it by subclassing UITableView and the UITableViewCell's event are not being overridden maybe you are doing something else

Comment: thank Joshua, it was my fault. I used `Category` on `UITableView` and implemented `touchesBegan:withEvent:`. That's why `UITableViewCell`s event got cancelled. However, i don't understand the differences between these two, subclassing and category, and why does category cancelled events on `UITableViewCell` while subclassing doesn't.

Comment: hi @PhamHoan, category vs subclass is already answered in here http://stackoverflow.com/a/522942/2301271

Comment: OK, sorry, I forgot to mark you answer.
For people who will have the same problem as mine. Follow Josh's answer and implement `[scrollViewWillBeginDragging:]`. You will be able to dismiss keyboard by touch or drag on UITableView.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

Add an empty imageview covering whole view(size of device), then add the gesture recognizer for that imageview and then in the call back method write the below code .

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    UIImageView *image;//your IBOutlet imageview
    UITapGestureRecognizer *recog=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(called:)];
    [image addGestureRecognizer:recog];
}    

-(void)called:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] endEditing:YES];
}
```